# Point-Line distance calculation

Tags: c++, math, 3d, 2d

I tryed to write code for calculating point-line distance. I found a lot of calculations on the internet but I am not sure if I understand right. I found some equations for lines and it seems like equations for calculating point-plane distance in 3D. I think it is the same but in 2 dimensional.

I have some experiences with 3D point-plane distance calculations. I calculated parameters **A,B,C,D** from **3 points vec3** (plane definition) and to get distance just apply this equation with **vec3** point **(x,y,z)**.

Plane equation: **Ax + By + Cz = D**

Line equation should be: **Ax + By = C**

Line equation should work similary by applying equation with **vec2** point **(x,y)**.

**My problem is** how to calculate parameters **A,B,C** from this equation with **2 points vec2** (line definition)?

**Any simply programming/mathematic explanation?**

Plane with 3 points:

```
Plane(vec3 p0, vec3 p1, vec3 p2) {
    vec3 v = p1 - p0;
    vec3 u = p2 - p0;
    vec3 n = cross(v, u);

    normalize(n);

    //Result A,B,C,D
    A = n.x;
    B = n.y;
    C = n.z;
    D = dot(vec3(-n.x, -n.y, -n.z), p0);
}
```

Plane with 2 points:

```
Line(vec2 p0, vec2 p1) {

    //...

    //Result A,B,C
    A = (?);
    B = (?);
    C = (?);
}
```

Thanks.

**PS: Sorry for my english. :/**

**Update:**

**Solved!**

I found answer after hour of calculations and it's similar to plane equation.

**Programming:**

```
Line(vec2 p0, vec2 p1) {
    vec2 l = p1 - p0;

    vec2 n = l.cross();
    n.normalize();

    //Result a,b,c 
    a = n.x;
    b = n.y;
    c = vec2::dot(vec2(-n.x, -n.y), p0);
}
```

Difference is in cross product of vec2. It's someting like this:

```
vec2 cross(vec2 p) { //Only one parameter
    return vec2(y, -x);
}
```

**Mathematic:**

P1 - start point of line

P2 - end point of line

1) ***N = x(P2 - P1)***

Where "x" is cross product of vector (swap elemets and negate element x) --->  x(V) = [Vy, -Vx]

(I'm not sure is this operation is official but result of that should be vector which is perpendicular to that parameter)

2) ***N = N / |N|*** *(normalize vector N)*

*Where |N| is length of vector N*

3) *Result A:* ***a = Nx***

4) *Result B:* ***b = Ny***

5) ***N' = -N***

6) *Result C:* ***c = (N').(P1)***

*Where "(N').(P1)" is dot product of vectors N' and P1*

**PS:**

This formula **d = (|(x_2-x_1)x(x_1-x_0)|)/(|x_2-x_1|)** is right. It works. But I need to use equation **ax + by + c = 0** because I need to know if it's on left or right side from line (positive of negaive distance) and it's better for programming. Thanks for answers.

Still sorry for my english. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but it sounds like you have a line defined by two points, and you want to find the distance between that line and a third point?  As you've seen, you can't uniquely determine A,B,C and D from just two points -- there are an infinite number of planes that contain that line.

If x_1 and x_2 are the 3-d vectors representing the points defining the line, and x_0 is the point
you're trying to find the distance to, the formula is:

```
d   =   (|(x_2-x_1)x(x_1-x_0)|)/(|x_2-x_1|)
```

(In this formula, 'x' denotes the 3-d cross product, '-' denotes vector subtraction, and |v| represents the length of vector v.)

[Point-Line Distance--3-dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html)

Comment: Yes, I want to find distance between that line and third point. But I want to do that in 2D not 3D. And I don't want to determine A,B,C,D as plane from 2 points but only A,B,C as line to use equation ax + by + c = 0. I use this [Point-Line Distance--2-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) but I didn't found calculation of parameters A,B and C if I have line defined by 2 vec2 points. Can you help me? Thank.

Comment: The 2-D case is a special case of the 3-d formula I gave.  Just set all the z components to 0.  (But why mention planes at all if you're only interested in two dimensions?)